# How to sort dictionary by values in inner dictionary

Tags: python

```
{1: {'p_place': {'x': 0.65, 'y': 0.255, 'z': 0.279}, 'q_place': {'q0': 1.0, 'q1': 0.0, 'q2': 0.0, 'q3': 0.0}, 'offset_pick': {'x': (0.0,), 'y': (0.0,), 'z': (0.05,)}, 'centroid_upper': {'x': (0.65,), 'y': (0.2549999999999998,), 'z': (0.329,)}}, 2: {'p_place': {'x': 0.65, 'y': 0.255, 'z': 0.279}, 'q_place': {'q0': 1.0, 'q1': 0.0, 'q2': 0.0, 'q3': 0.0}, 'offset_pick': {'x': (0.0,), 'y': (0.0,), 'z': (0.05,)}, 'centroid_upper': {'x': (0.65,), 'y': (0.2549999999999998,), 'z': (0.329,)}}}
```

I have this kind of dictionary. I want to sort it by value `Y` and `Z` of `p_place`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try anything at all?

```
newd = sorted(dct, key=lambda el: (el['p_place']['y'],el['p_place']['z']))
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this one. But it doesnt work. it say

Comment: newd = sorted(parts, key=lambda el: el['p_place']['y'], el['p_place']['z'])
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: Thank you, it helped me! I just fixed:newd = sorted(
            parts, key=lambda x: (parts[x]['p_place']['y'], parts[x]['p_place']['z'])
        )